# possible?: changing tickValues in IDL

Tags: idl-programming-language

how can I change the tickvalues of 3D axes in IDL? I have a data array of 200 x 200, and the tick values range from 0 to 200. But I want to have tickvalues from 3417000 to 3419000 for x and from 5334000 to 5336000 for y.

Thanks a lot,
Harald

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution for my problem:

```
!X.TICKNAME = ['3417000', '3417500', '3418000', '3418500', $
    '3419000']
!X.TICKS = 4
```

Thanks,

Harald

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the keywords `XTICKNAMES` and `XTICKS` instead of the global system variables.